# Kiel traduki „breaking news“ al Esperanto?

Tags: translation

Temas pri novaĵo, kiu estas tiel grava, ke indas interrompi la ordinaran elsendon de televido, radio, ktp.

Mi ne povas trovi ekzemplojn de tiu esprimo en PIV, nek en ReVo. Kompreneble, <strike>*rompanta novaĵo*</strike> ne estas ĝusta, sed ĉu iu el la sekvaj taŭgas:

> - *grava novaĵo* — sed multaj novaĵoj povas esti gravaj, kaj oni ne povas interrompi ordinarajn elsendojn pro ĉiu grava novaĵo
> - *elstara novaĵo* — mi ne scias ĉu ĉi tiu esprimo estas ĝusta

En la bulgara, oni uzas la adjektivon *извънредна* en tia okazo, kiu oni povas traduki kiel *eksterorda*, sed mi ne scias ĉu tiu vorto taŭgas en Esperanto.

Do, kiu estas la plej bona maniero esprimi la sencon?

Answer (score 3):

Mi sugestas la esprimojn *paŭziga bulteno* aŭ *urĝa sciigo* aŭ *interrompa informado/anonco*, aŭ ion similan.

Oni povas uzi *novaĵoj* aŭ *aktualaĵoj* aŭ *neprokrasteblaĵoj*, sed laŭ mi tiuj vortoj estas pli precize titoloj de bultenoj, ne ĉiam bultenoj mem.

Answer (score 2):

Plej freŝa novaĵo.
Evoluantaj novaĵoj.